# assign lambda to a variable and call it later

Tags: c++11, lambda

*It might be a duplicate question, but I couldn't find it, probably due to probably lacking terminology.*

Here is the problem: I would like to assign a lambda function to a variable that would be called later on.

```cpp
class MyClass
{
  public:
    MyClass( QWdiget* widget );

    void doSomething();

  private:
    QWidget* my_widget;
    std::function<QString()> my_text;
}

MyClass::MyClass( QWdiget* widget )
    : my_text( [=](){return QString();} )
{
  if ( qobject_cast<QLabel*>( widget ) )
  {
    my_text = [=](){return my_widget ? qobject_cast<QLabel*>( my_widget )->text() : Qstring(); };
  }
  else if ( qobject_cast<QGroupBox*>( widget ) )
  {
    my_text = [=](){return my_widget ? qobject_cast<QGroupBox*>( my_widget )->title() : QString(); };
  }
  else
  {
    return;
  }
  my_widget = widget;
}

MyClass::DoSomething()
{
  QString str = my_text();
  ....whatever
}
```

I am getting a crash and can't find out.

**Edit:**

Implementing correctly the default value partially solved the issue.
Now, `qobject_cast` crashes.

Comment: Would be nice to get a compileable peace of code. If I want to check your code, I have to remove all the not needed things e.g. Q....

Comment: If you get a crash, I suggest you start by using a debugger to catch the crash in action, and locate where it happens in your code. And make sure that the `widget` object you pass to the constructor stays alive until the lambda has been called. And is not a null pointer of course. And what if none of the `if` conditions are true? How will you handle that?

Comment: I added the default implementation (was missing in code example), and added check on the pointer. Still getting the crash in qobject_cast.

Comment: Then you need to show us how you create the instance of `MyClass`, and what you pass for pointer to the constructor. The object whose pointer you pass, it *will* still be alive when you call `DoSomething` and the lambda? Preferably please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: A bit difficult to provide a minimal example here. I just tried to give the widget as a parameter to the lambda, i.e. do `my_text(my_widget)` and it works. This means I have an issue with the capturing group?

Comment: I will bring a minimal example later on.

Comment: Oh, is it `my_wdiget` (misspelled but used commonly throughout the code you show) or `my_widget` (which you assign to in the constructor)? Or do you have two variables, just with different spelling? And why don't you use the constructor initializer list to initialize `my_wdiget` (or whatever) instead of assigning to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add default implementation like this:

```
if ( qobject_cast<QLabel*>( widget ) )
{
  my_text = [=](){return  qobject_cast<QLabel*>( my_wdiget )->text(); };
}
else if ( qobject_cast<QGroupBox*>( widget ) )
{
  my_text = [=](){return  qobject_cast<QGroupBox*>( my_wdiget )->title(); };
}
else
{
  my_text = [=](){ return QString(); };
}
```

Comment: default implementation was there but incomplete. It brought me a bit further, updating the original post